# Lotus Notes 8.5 HTML signature with image, image not aligned horizontally

Tags: html, image, lotus-notes, signature, alignment

I have the following problem with Lotus Notes email HTML signatures with image. The code for HTML signature is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>signature</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 </head>
 <body>

 <!--CSS can skip-->
 <style type="text/css">
   #url {
    color:rgb(0, 136, 204) !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
   }
   #outer {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', Lucida Grande, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
    font-size:11px; 
    color:#555555;
   }
   #padding {
    padding-top:10px;
   }
   #div.img {
    width:288px;
    height:40px;
    padding-left:10px;
   }
   #left {
    float:left;
   }
   #right {
    width:100%;
   }
 </style>

<!--Signature itself-->
<div id="outer">
 <div id="header">
  [Name FamilyName] | [Title]
 </div>
 <div id="padding"></div>
 <div id="left">
  Line1<br>
  Line2<br>
  Line3<br>
 </div>
 <div id="right">
  <img src="file:///LocalPathToImage.png" style="padding-left:10px">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Idea is to have signature where image is aligned to the right with text on the left.
In browser alignment is correct, though when putting it as signature in Lotus Notes 8.5 (File->Preferences->Mail->Signature->HTML), image is always at the bottom.

How to make sure that in HTML signatures the alignment (float) properties are preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS rules seem to work fine in Chrome (I checked on JSFiddle), but the HTML engine in Lotus Notes is likely far off when it comes to adherence to CSS rules.  I'd suggest rewriting this to use tables instead, you will probably have more success.

Comment: Thank you, rewritten with tables, and alignment is preserved!

Comment: Question 1 is answered. Please, have a look at Question 2.

Comment: Re: Question 2 - Unless that image hosted on the Internet this isn't possible. I've not tested this, but have you tried using data uris to embed the image? I think outlook uses this trick:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

Comment: Tried now with embedding URI of the image, but now I don't see image in HTML signature even on my side, though in browser image is displayed. I have also tried an image hosted in the Internet, it was not displayed on my side either.

Comment: I can see that images being part of HTML signature and being properly displayed are possible (received such emails), I just don't know which settings I should have.

Comment: @aza07, You'll have better luck getting your question answered if you submit it as a new question.  That will give others a chance to see it, and it fits the StackOverflow model of having one question, with many answers, rather than squeezing two questions into one page.  Also, please don't accept an answer and then change the question and unaccept the answer.  The accepted answer is meant to show someone coming to the site that the question was answered.  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954328/lotus-notes-8-5-html-signature-with-image-image-not-shown-on-receivers-side

Answer (score 1):

You should use inline css, because not all email client will read your style sheet at the top.